# mysql error:Cannot add or update a child row: mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

when i am adding data into child table i am getting following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`rogue`.`products_tags`, CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_2`
FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `products` (`ProductID`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

my parent table structure is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Image` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ImageUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LinkUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `InsertBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `InsertDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdateBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

child table is product_tags. here is my table structure:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products_tags`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_tags` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TagID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `InsertBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `InsertDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ProductID` (`ProductID`),
  KEY `TagID` (`TagID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `products_tags`
--

ALTER TABLE `products_tags`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TagID`) 
  REFERENCES `tags` (`TagID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) 
  REFERENCES `products` (`ProductID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

my query is:

```
INSERT INTO `products_tags` (`InsertBy`, `InsertDate`, `ProductID`, `TagID`)
VALUES (NULL,'2014-01-06 13:36:28','13','5'), 
(NULL,'2014-01-06 13:36:28','13','4'), (NULL,'2014-01-06 13:36:28','14','5'),
(NULL,'2014-01-06 13:36:28','14','4')
```

Comment: Do you have a row in `product` with `product_id = 14`?

Comment: Do you see all the questions in the **Related** list with the same error? Doesn't any of them answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

First insert the row in parent table and save it after that insert in child table. This error comes when you try to insert a value in foreign key column which is not present in primary key column.